# Mismatched input '' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'. Error on pine-script

Tags: pine-script

```
if buyEntry

lowestLow = lowest(source, length)
strategy.entry("BBandLE", strategy.long, qty=position_size, stop=lower, oca_name="BollingerBands", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="BBandLE")

lowestLowExit = strategy.exit("BBandLE", "BBandLE", stop=lowestLow, limit=lowestLow + take_profit_distance, trail_points=stop_loss_distance, comment="TP")
```

Error Mismatched input 'lowestLow' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

Answer (score 0):

The body of your if block must be indented by 4 spaces or 1 tab.

```
<var_declarationX> = if <condition>
    <var_decl_then0>
    <var_decl_then1>
    ...
    <var_decl_thenN>
else if [optional block]
    <var_decl_else0>
    <var_decl_else1>
    ...
    <var_decl_elseN>
else
    <var_decl_else0>
    <var_decl_else1>
    ...
    <var_decl_elseN>
    <return_expression_else>
```

You can read more about the statements from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#tabs).